# remap ctrl-k in atom doesn't work

Tags: atom-editor

I have the following entries in my keymap.cson:

```
'.workspace':
    'ctrl-k': 'core:move-up'
    'ctrl-j': 'core:move-down
```

The ctrl-j mapping works, the ctrl-k doesn't. Isn't it possible to remap ctrl-k ?

Answer (score 2):

The following works:

```
'atom-text-editor':
   'ctrl-k': 'core:move-up'
```